# Addressed event subscription

Tags: c#, events

In several of my projects, it is becoming apparent that I need something slightly more powerful than the standard .NET events.

Basically, I want the option of within a message pump, having callbacks (events) raised to specific subscribers when the component they're interested changes.

This could be a specific I/O changing state (e.g. button closing contact) for one project, or a message received from a wireless ethernet for a specific MAC address in another.

My current line of thinking is to use a dictionary, and list of delegates against each address (for this example).

I haven't debugged this yet but is the following along the right lines?

```
class CustomSubscription
{
    public delegate void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs args);

    public class DataReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public byte[] data;
    }

    private readonly Dictionary<int, List<DataReceivedHandler>> _subscribers;

    public CustomSubscription()
    {
        _subscribers = new Dictionary<int, List<DataReceivedHandler>>();
    }

    public void AddSubscriber(int address, DataReceivedHandler callback)
    {
        if (false == _subscribers.ContainsKey(address))
        {
            _subscribers.Add(address, new List<DataReceivedHandler>());
        }
        _subscribers[address].Add(callback);
    }

    public void RemoveSubscriber(int address, DataReceivedHandler callback)
    {
        if (false == _subscribers.ContainsKey(address))
        {
            return;
        }
        if (_subscribers[address].Contains(callback))
        {
            _subscribers[address].Remove(callback);
        }
    }

    public void HandleIncommingData(int address, object sender, byte[] payload)
    {
        if (false == _subscribers.ContainsKey(address))
        {
            // Nothing subscribed - take no action
            return;
        }

        // Raise callbacks with all subscribers
        foreach (DataReceivedHandler callback in _subscribers[address])
        {
            callback(sender, new DataReceivedEventArgs
                                 {
                                     data = payload
                                 });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=CSharpMessenger_Extended

Comment: Does this not restrict to one subscriber per event type? I want the ability to have several interested parties for one event type (which my snippet allows)

Comment: Nope. See the example `Messenger<float>.Broadcast("speed changed", speed);` Keyword here is the `Broadcast`

Comment: Ah, had my 'C' hat on and thinking in terms of function pointers (forgetting the chaining that comes with delegates).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to implement an event aggregator pattern. There are plenty implementations already on the web. You can start from here, for example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343980/event-aggregator-implementation-sample-best-practices

Comment: Some good examples there (and knowing what the 'official' name helps when googling!). The link to CSharpMessanger_Extended that I4V linked to is closer to what I'm trying to achieve though.

Comment: @l33tmike sure, pick the implementation which suits your needs and go off it. Using one, which does not use strongly typed messages, though, (while it normally involeves less coding) might turn into hell, when it comes to debugging a large application. Choose wisely :)

Comment: yeah, I'll probably go along with a homebrew - I don't need a fully abstracted aggregator but have adapted to use generics and object locking the code I posted originally.